# Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions $f_j$ on interval $[0,1]$ satisfying $|f_j(t)-f_j(s)| < |s-t|^a$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that sequence of functions $f_j$ on the interval $[0,1]$ satisfies 
$$
|f_j(t)-f_j(s)| < |s-t|^a
$$ 
for all $s,t$ element of $[0,1]$, $j=0,1,\ldots$, and for some $a \in (0,1]$. Further assume that the sequence of functions $f_j$ converges pointwise to a limit function $f$ on [0,1]. Prove that sequence converges uniformly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $f=0$.

Since $x\mapsto x^a$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, For $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that
$$
|s-t| < \delta \Rightarrow |s-t|^a < \epsilon
$$
Choose $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n$ such that, for all $s\in [0,1], \exists t_i$ such that $|s-t_i| < \delta$. Now, $f_j(t_i) \to 0$, so $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
|f_j(t_i)| < \epsilon \quad\forall j \geq N\quad\forall i\in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}
$$
Hence, for all $s\in [0,1]$
$$
|f_j(s)| \leq |s-t_i|^a + \epsilon < 2\epsilon \quad\forall j\geq N
$$
Hence, $f_j \to 0$ uniformly.